# Visual Studio 2017 Debug Multiple Instances of the Same Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have created a single command line application that handles different jobs per a command line argument.  For instance, the "-w" starts a web project and "-c" runs a simple command line process.

Sometimes these two projects have to speak with each other.  For instance, I start one instance with "-w" and an API web application launches.  I start a second instance with "-c" and a command line application connects via API and processes some returned data.

I understand that I can debug multiple different projects at the same time, but is there a way to debug multiple instances of the SAME project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Start two instances of Visual studio with the same project. In each instance you can start a debug session for the same project (with a different parameter)

Comment: This is for sure a valid option.  Just curious if I am missing anything where this could be done in a single instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

1. Debug your program normally to get the first instance
2. Right click on your project in Solution Explorer and select `Debug` -> `Start New Instance`

You can also launch other programs in your solution as well.

Comment: When I do this, it kills the first instance and the second instance never stops.  Looks like there might be some conflict somewhere.

Comment: Additionally, if I could get them both to start up as you noted, how could I get the two instances to have different command line arguments?

Comment: Not sure why it would kill it.  What version of VS are you using?  Express?  Do you have any code in your program looking for a second instance?  This answer won't help with different arguments.  I have an idea for that.  New answer coming in a minute.

Comment: I am running VS 2017 Pro.  It wouldn't be surprising that something is a little off with my install.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass different startup arguments to each instance, than you can do following:

For each instance you want to run:

1. **Add New Empty Project to the same Solution**
2. **Under Project Properties -> Debugging** specify

   - **Command** -> for example absolute path to the project .exe
   - **Command Arguments**
   - eventually other options like working dir , etc.
3. **Under Solution Properties choose Multiple startup projects** and **select projects you want to Debug at the same time**

Now if you hit F5 you can debug all projects you want eventually some multiple instances with specific command line arguments for each one.